# Static vs REST routing with clojure ring

Tags: clojure, jetty, url-routing, ring

I'm writing an angular/clojure ring webapp. All routes to the ring side will have an "/api" prefix and will be routed with compojure.

Serving upp all other static file with ring seems a bit messy though.

Is there a good way to direct "/api/whatever" requests to ring and all other to be served up as static files using jetty? or using any other major web server, like apache, nginx, lighttpd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We put nginx infront of jetty and have nginx configured to serve the static stuff (actually redirects to a CDN) directly and proxy all the app stuff to jetty. In production jetty is running on a separate load balancer though this works out the same if they are running on the same instance.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. Are you using a more lightweight solution for testing? Local nginx with proxy of different ports?

Comment: When people are working on both frontend and api stuff they can run nginx on a vitualbox instance on their laptop with the front end code mapped into it with a shared folder and the api code either run through emacs+lein or on it's own AWS instance produced through pallet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run clojure Ring handlers with Nginx without any Java Web Server, eg. Jetty. please try [Nginx-Clojure module](https://github.com/xfeep/nginx-clojure).